# How to integrate Angular js with IBM BPM 8.0 client side human service

Tags: ibm-bpm

Currently I am working on ibm bpm 8.0 and we are having requirement to angular js in the client side human services.
I have imported jquery.js and angular.js in process app as web files and used those files in my coach view and successfully able to run angular js code in custom html, But how can I use angular js with IBM BPM provided controls like (output text, input, button etc) and can achieve the two way binding?

Comment: The controls in **Responsive Coaches Toolkit** are built with AngularJS and Bootstrap. This toolkit is officially integrated into BPM 8.5.7 

More details at [BPM Responsive Coaches](https://developer.ibm.com/bpm/blog/resources/bpm-responsive-coaches/)

Comment: @ParkerWang : is there any such toolkit for 8.0.1.3 ??

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not such toolkit for 8.0.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Already existing coach view are build in and are intended for specific functionalities, I did not get why you want to change this and want two way binding. I don't think we have better way to do this without modifying those existing views. But below might work.

onLoad event of any coach view, you can attached additional programmatically created DOM elements to existing coach view. This way, you can attached AngularJS related html elements to exiting coach view. Also you can attached any event with this newly added DOM elements to react to user actions. on change event of existing coach view you can pass data to newly added DOM elements.

Below should help you on how to use AngularJS which you already have done.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFPJS_8.5.7/com.ibm.wbpm.wle.editor.doc/topics/t_create_lite_control.html